# External display suddenly not detected

Tags: display, hdmi, external-monitor, xrandr

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad U410 running Ubuntu Desktop 13.04.  I have an external monitor that I connect to via HDMI, and it's worked flawlessly for six months.  I plug in my laptop, it detects the display.  The "change display" key built into the laptop works for switching between the two screens.  Never any problems.

This afternoon, when I reconnected my computer after taking it into another room for a bit, it didn't work.  When I open up Display settings, it can't detect the display. I tried disconnecting/reconnecting everything multiple times.  And most strangely, that same "change display" key now behaves like a Super key, opening the dash instead of toggling the display.  Nothing at all changed between when I plugged it in this morning and when it stopped working a few hours later.  I tried xrandr, that doesn't detect it either.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Same issue here NChase... specially wierd this superKey+Monitor activating the dash... anyhow... I found out that if I "disconnect" any devices plugged in (USB, BT Mouse, etc) and restart I get the external screen working again... Maybe a bug indeed... hope some 'good soul' can fix it... Have you had any other solutions over there?

Comment: Very interesting, just experienced the same and restarting with all USB devices detached did solve it indeed!